# How Do I Use a Hidden Parameter in a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am attempting to pass parameters that are defined in a Jenkins configuration to a declarative pipeline. When I do this with the built in string, everything works fine:

```
string(name: 'rv', defaultValue: 'none', description: 'the release version')
```

Since these value should not be edited by the user in the Build with Parameters screen, I switched to using the [hidden parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/hidden-parameter/):

```
hidden(name: 'rv', defaultValue: 'none', description: 'the release version')
```

But this gives me an error when the pipeline script is run:

```
WorkflowScript: 30: Invalid parameter type "hidden". Valid parameter types: [booleanParam, buildSelector, choice, credentials, file, gitParameter, text, password, run, string]
```

Is there a method by which I can use the hidden parameter in a declarative Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Would you consider using the `password` parameter instead:
`password(name: 'rv', defaultValue: 'none', description: 'the release version')` , if it masks your value you should be fine?

Comment: The password parameter would not solve the issue I am looking at. I am not concerned about the user being able to know the value of the variable (and having the value shown in the config is important). I would just like to make the "Build with Parameters" screen look cleaner. I have worked around the hidden parameter not working by adding a headline saying "ignore the following parameters", but this relies on the user following instructions.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this issue? How to hide parameters in the pipeline?

Comment: I have not, though I saw last week that the failure is a known bug and the plug-in is under semi-active development again and there are open tasks against fixing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue and by coincidence I found the solution.
Supposing, that you have the already mentioned 'Hidden Param Plugin', add the following line to your Jenkinsfile in the `parameters` section and it should work:

```
    [$class     : 'WHideParameterDefinition',
     name       : 'HIDDEN_PARAM',
     description: 'Hidden param for...']
```

Hope this helps you as well.

Comment: I was able to use this workaround after switching from declarative pipeline parameters to a parameters array with `stage{ steps{ script{ properties([ parameters([ ... ]) ]) } } }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', 
    parameterDefinitions: [
        [$class: 'WHideParameterDefinition', name: 'isValid', defaultValue:  'false']
    ]
]])
```

I found my answer here: https://copyprogramming.com/howto/jenkins-hidden-parameters